# Wait for binding update, then lose focus on ListViewItem

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

So I have a **ListView**. It has a **ItemSource** and a **SelectedItem**.

The SelectedItem has a bool property that toggles the visibility of the **Button** and **TextBox**.

When you press in the **ListViewItem** I want to be able to toggle the visibility on and off, even if I just spam the row.

The solution is partly working, except that **SelectedItem** is only fired when the Item don't have focus. So when I have toggled one time, I have to do it to another item to toggle the first again.

[image]

I have thought about **code-behind**, add something to the **GotFocus**-method, but can't think of what I have to do there.

**Suggestions**?

**XAML:**

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"          
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"            
              ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="False"           
              Background="White"  
              ItemsSource="{Binding Activities}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedActivity, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <ListViewItemPresenter
                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                        SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
                        CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                        CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                        DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                        DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                        FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
                        FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                        PlaceholderBackground="White"
                        PointerOverBackground="LightGray"
                        PointerOverForeground="DarkGray"
                        SelectedBackground="White"
                        SelectedForeground="DimGray"
                        SelectedPointerOverBackground="White"
                        PressedBackground="White"
                        SelectedPressedBackground="White"
                        DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                        DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                        ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        CheckMode="Inline"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.Header>
            <StackPanel Background="#8c8c8c" 
                                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                    FlowDirection="LeftToRight" 
                                    Padding="8,8,8,8">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                                                        FontSize="18" 
                                                        Foreground="White" 
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                        Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,10,0,10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                                        Grid.Row="0" 
                                        Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        Margin="6,2,6,2">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="20" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           Foreground="DimGray" 
                                           TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                                           Text="{Binding Activity.Description}"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="15" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           Foreground="DimGray" 
                                           Text="{Binding Activity.Condition}"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <Button Grid.Row="0" 
                                    Grid.Column="1" 
                                    Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                                    Margin="6"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    Background="Transparent"
                                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    Command="{Binding ToggleMeasureCompletionCommand}">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                            FontSize="35"
                                            Foreground="DimGray"
                                            Text="&#xE739;"
                                            Margin="8"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                            Visibility="{Binding IsCompleted, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                            FontSize="35"
                                            Foreground="DimGray"
                                            Text="&#xE73A;"
                                            Margin="8"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                           Visibility="{Binding IsCompleted, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                    <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsInFocus, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" PlaceholderText="Kommentar til tiltak" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="5" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Flag" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White" Padding="10,5,10,5">
                            <Button.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.5" />
                            </Button.Background>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**C# - property:**

```
public SelectedItemViewModel SelectedActivity
        {
            get { return _selectedActivity; }
            set
            {
                _selectedActivity = value;
                SelectedActivity.IsInFocus = !SelectedActivity.IsInFocus;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code. As it is, we are not able to help you with the problem.

Comment: @NahuelIanni, added XAML

Comment: And also the properties on your VM/CS :) I want to see how you're changing the bool value and how you manage it.

Comment: @NahuelIanni Added the property, nothing special. All events are fired, and working. Only the focus that are the issue

Comment: You can write  SelectedActivity.IsInFocus = !SelectedActivity.IsInFocus; code in selection changed event instead of in setter.

Comment: @Archana Can you provide a example? Something like this? Would like to do as little as possible in the code-behind

 private void MeasureActivity_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((MeasureItemsViewModel)DataContext).ToggleFocus();

            var lv = sender as ListView;
            if (lv != null)
            {
                lv.SelectedItem = null;
            }
        }

Comment: why are you making selecteditem null?

Comment: @Archana Because if I just call the method I just Achieve the same as the setter. It will change, but still have focus, so I can't toggle again

Comment: For the first time IsInFocus=false right? then in selectionchanged event you will make it to true but it wont reflect in ui. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @Archana SelectionChanged will not be fired the second time. Since the Item has focus, it will not fire any selection-events. So I have to choose another item, then go back to toggle again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106610/discussion-between-archana-and-simonkaspers1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this code `SelectedActivity.IsInFocus = !SelectedActivity.IsInFocus` inside ItemClick event of listview. 
You can write inside Taped event also